# Linebreak on .txt file everytime I hit submit button

Tags: php, html, parameters, text-files

I wanted my code to save the data into a text file. I got it to do this:

```
Name: Geo
Address: California
Phone Number: 661212121
# of Boxes: 1
Scheduled Date: Tues
```

But, every time I hit the submit button again with the new data out of the HTML it just replaces the old data in the text file.

```
Name: Paul
Address: Sweden
Phone Number: 1234
# of Boxes: 5
Scheduled Date: Wed
```

I wanted to make the output look like:

```
Name: Geo
Address: California
Phone Number: 661212121
# of Boxes: 1
Scheduled Date: Tues

Name: Paul
Address: Sweden
Phone Number: 1234
# of Boxes: 5
Scheduled Date: Wed
```

My HTML:

```
     <form action='testing.php' method='GET'>
    Name: <br/>
    <input type='text' name='name'/>
    <br/>
    Address: <br/>
    <input type='text' name='address'/>
    <br/>
    Contact Number: <br/>
    <input type='text' name='phone'/>
    <br/>
    # of Boxes: <br/>
    <input type='text' name='box'/>
    <br/>
    Scheduled Date <br/>
    <input type='text' name='date'/>
    <br/>
    <input type='submit' value='SUBMIT'/>
</form>
```

And the PHP:

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['name'];
$address = $_GET['address'];
$phone = $_GET['phone'];
$box = $_GET['box'];
$date = $_GET['date'];

$file_handle = fopen("pickup.txt", "w");
$file_contents = "Name:" . $name . "\r\n" . "Address:" . $address . "\r\n" . "Phone Number:" . $phone . "\r\n" . "# of Boxes:" . $box . "\r\n" . "Scheduled Date:" . $date;

fwrite($file_handle, $file_contents);
fclose($file_handle);
print "file created and written to pickups.txt";
```

Comment: Maybe change: `$file_handle = fopen("pickup.txt", "w");` to `$file_handle = fopen("pickup.txt", "a");` So you append stuff! with `w` mode you overwrite the file very time!

Comment: `'w' Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.`

Comment: or just `file_put_contents($filename, $contents, FILE_APPEND)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the append option -

```
$file_handle = fopen("pickup.txt", "a"); // replaced 'w'
```

See [fopen modes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php#mode)

> 'a' Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the end of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

Comment: No worries, you're here to learn @xGeo If the answer was helpful, please accept it by clicking the big check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$file_handle = fopen("pickup.txt", "a");
```

along with

```
$file_contents = "Name:" . $name . "\r\n" . "Address:" . $address . "\r\n" . "Phone Number:" .      $phone . "\r\n" . "# of Boxes:" . $box . "\r\n" . "Scheduled Date:" . $date . "\r\n";
```